# How can I retrieve the name of the S3 bucket a CloudFront distribution is using?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is there any way I can ask the CloudFront API for the name of the bucket it uses on Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via the [GET Distribution](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/GetDistribution.html) action:

> To get the information about a distribution, you do a GET on the
>   2012-03-15/distribution/ resource.

Have a look at the sample syntax in the *Responses* section, which specifically includes fragments for either `S3Origin` or `CustomOrigin`, e.g. abbreviated:

```xml
<Distribution xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-03-15/">
   <!-- ... -->
   <DistributionConfig>
      <S3Origin>
         <DNSName>myawsbucket.s3.amazonaws.com</DNSName>
         <OriginAccessIdentity>origin-access-identity/cloudfront/E127EXAMPLE51Z</OriginAccessIdentity>
      </S3Origin>   
      <!-- ... -->
   </DistributionConfig>
</Distribution>
```

Please note that *The S3Origin element is returned only if you use an Amazon S3 origin for your distribution*, whereas *The CustomOrigin element is returned only if you use a custom origin for your distribution*. Furthermore, for *more information about the CustomOrigin element and the S3Origin element, see [DistributionConfig Complex Type](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/DistributionConfigDatatype.html).*